# Accessing the callback from a node module

Tags: node.js

simple Q: How do I access the callback from `rimraf`? See [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rimraf).

Can't wrap my head around how to structure the code - I'm trying for example:

```
var rimraf = require('rimraf');
var removeDir = rimraf(p, callback);

var p = 'docs/mydirectory';
removeDir(p, function(cb){
  console.log(cb)
});
```

But receiving `callback undefined`.. I'm probably doing something completely wrong! Can someone point me in the right direction? Cheers

Comment: Please show the function definition that is assigned to the `rimraf` variable.  We need to see that function because that's where you're passing the `callback`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var removeDir = rimraf(p, callback);
```

Is calling the rimraf function, not setting a reference to it.  If you want to call it removeDir then use it instead...

```
var removeDir = require('rimraf');

var p = 'docs/mydirectory';
removeDir(p, function(err){
  console.log('dir removed');
});
```

Comment: Supoy'b - this is it, confused myself!